# ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: relation table does not exist)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 3 tables (Freebie, Company, FreebieCompany) and FreebieCompany is the intermediary table. 2 tables (Freebie, Company) use **has_many** association and is being connected by the middle table. I can access the Company table to get the freebies but not Freebies to Companies.

```
class Company < ApplicationRecord
   has_many :freebie_companies
   has_many :freebies, through: :freebie_companies
end
```

```
class Freebie < ApplicationRecord
   has_many :freebie_companies
   has_many :companies, through: :freebie_companies
```

```
class FreebieCompany < ApplicationRecord
   belongs_to :freebie
   belongs_to :company
end
```

FreebieCompany have both company_id and freebie_id.
I can access the Freebies of a certain company, but not the Companies of a certain Freebie.

I did rake db:reset, drop, create, migrate, setup and db:schema:load but nothing really solved the problem. I double checked the migration version and all tables are listed on the schema.

Maybe another perspective can help me find the solution to this. Every time I try to access the companies, it gives me the error below.

**`> freebie.companies`**

**```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "freebie_companies" does not exist)
LINE 1: ...ompanies".* FROM "companies" INNER JOIN "freebi...

```
It's my first time to post here, and I've been using my whole day to find the answer to this one.

Any help is very appreciated. Thank you so much!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really looks like you don't have the association represented in your database.
It would be good to see your schema to be sure that your models are being referenced correctly in your DB.

Usually when generating associated models, we run:

`rails g model FreebieCompany freebie:references company:references`.

This will generate two columns for each association in the FreebieCompanies table.

```
t.bigint "freebie_id", null: false
t.index ["freebie_id"], name: "index_freebie_companies_on_freebie_id
t.bigint "company_id", null: false
t.index ["company_id"], name: "index_freebie_companies_on_company_id
```

[Here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) you can find the doc about *has_many :through*

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to mention that I use multiple databases. Primary and Superadmin Database.

Here are my new models:

Intermediary Table:

```
class FreebieCompany < SuperadminsRecord
 belongs_to :company
 belongs_to :freebie
end
```

Main Tables:

```
class Freebie < SuperadminsRecord
 has_many :freebie_companies
 has_many :companies, through: :freebie_companies
end

class Company < ApplicationRecord
 has_many :freebie_companies
 has_many :freebies, through: :freebie_companies
end
```

For the migration file for inter. table:

```
class CreateFreebieCompanies < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
 def change
  create_table :create_freebie_companies do |t|
   t.references :company, foreign_key: {to_table: :freebies}
   t.integer :freebie_id

   t.timestamps null: false
  end
 end
end
```